# pointer * and & difference

Tags: pointers

I am confused on pointers in objective-c. I wrote a very simple program to try and understand

```
char* temp = "temp";
printf("temp - %s \n", temp);
printf("*temp - %d \n", *temp);
printf("&temp - %s \n", &temp);
printf("&(*temp) - %s \n", &(*temp));
```

In this example, temp is a pointer to char with a default value of "temp". What does *temp, &temp mean? The output is:

```
temp - temp
*temp - 116
&temp - 00@
&(*temp) - temp
```

So temp is the pointer. When I print temp, it prints the value "temp". *temp is the value of the pointer or the address of the variable it points to. What is &temp? Is this the address of the pointer itself?

I wrote a second program in which I assign pointer to address of n (&n).

```
int n = 50, x;
int *ptr;
ptr = &n;
x = *ptr;

printf("n - %d\n", n);
printf("ptr - %d\n", ptr);
printf("*ptr - %d\n", *ptr);
printf("x - %d\n", x);
```

The output is:

```
n - 50
ptr - 2271924
*ptr - 50
x - 50
```

n is 50 and x is undefined. ptr points to address of n. Why does *ptr print 50 and *temp prints 116? Is the difference between how I have defined the two pointers? I am trying to understand the basics. Thank you.

Comment: objective c? tags? here, have a potato

Comment: I am taking an objective-c course online. They are going through c first. Specifically pointers. Stackoverflow suggested tagging with c++. I have removed it.

Comment: @U-L Correct, this is a C question (but I think it's equally valid, although pointless, to tag it as Objective-C, since that language is a strict superset of C, unlike C++.) You will need to read the relevant chapter of a beginner C book.

Comment: okay. Thank you carbonic acid :). Cool name.

Comment: `*temp` is the value stored at the memory address equal to the value stored in `temp` variable (_pointed by the `temp`_). `&temp` is the memory address of the `temp` variable itself (_address of `temp`_). `&(*temp)` is the address of the value stored at the address stored in `temp`, which is `temp` itself. `printf("%s", var)` interprets `var` as pointer to a null-terminated string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we print out *temp, we go to the temp variable, locate the address that it holds (the one it points to), than print out whatever data is in that location.

When we print out &temp, we are asking for the address of the temp variable, not what it is pointing to.

For your second program, you assign the address of n (using &) to ptr. This way, when we choose to call *ptr, it's gonna locate the address stored in ptr (which is n's), and print out whatever n holds. So you then assigned the value *ptr points to, and store it in x.

In summary, when declaring a pointer, & will print out the address of the variable, * will print out what it points to, and nothing in front will print out the address of the variable it's pointing to.

Comment: Thanks Josh. Why does *temp print out 116. If I am understanding your logic, *temp should follow to the address and print out the value, which is "temp", no?

Comment: Well when you point to a bunch of char's like "temp", the pointer actually only points to the first character in it which is t. T has an asci value of 116 and you ask to print out a decimal using %d. If you did the same thing possible and ask to print out a char, I bet it would be t

Comment: Good catch. That makes sense. I guess to print it out, I would read till \0? or maybe there is a better way in C. but you have answered all my questions. Thank you !

Comment: @U-L `%d` makes `printf` to interpret its argument as `int`. `%s` makes it interpret as _pointer to a null-terminated string_ - it'll keep reading from address pointed by the argument until it reaches `\0`. The argument should be pointing to a valid location (or different bad things can happen).

Comment: oh @PetrBudnik, then I am not sure why I get "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" when I tried %s with *ptr.

Comment: @U-L `*ptr` is `50`. `printf("%s", *ptr)` means _print all characters starting with character located at decimal memory address `50` until you meet `\0` character_. Decimal memory address `50` is so small, it points, I'd say, to the protected area of process memory.

Comment: interesting. Thanks @PetrBudnik.